# Bypass PermissionError code in a loop in Python?

Tags: python, loops, error-handling

I have a Python question and can use your help!

I am using a GitHub library, `htrc-text-processing`, to clean text files of 10,000+ books and to output these cleaned books as new, cleaned text files. This is a custom library designed to clean specific text files I am using, and it works when cleaning a single text file (with minor glitches, like outputting the cleaned file twice instead of once; this glitch results in an error code). I am not bothered by the error code: the package works anyway. However, I need to use the package to clean all 10,000 books, not just one book.

The problem that I am running into is that when I attempt to clean all of the books in a loop, the loop stops once it hits the error code after cleaning the first book. I need the loop to keep going and clean the other books, even despite the error code--the error doesn't bother me, and the package works despite the error. **However, I can't figure out how to bypass the error code in a loop.**

I tried to bypass the error code using `except: pass`:

```
for x in text_sample:
  try:
    htrc_text_processing.clean_vol(x, out_dir) 
  except: 
     pass
```

However, this did not stop the error code from pausing my loop, so that I cannot clean the remaining 9,999 books.

This is the error code. The loop stops after processing the first text, `31924000106314.txt`, yielding the following error code. However, as stated above, I'm not bothered by this error--the code still works to produce the cleaned text file for `31924000106314.txt`. For me, the problem is not that there is an error, but **that I can't figure out how to bypass this annoying error code to continue running the loop through the other texts.**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\Users\MYNAME\anaconda3\lib\shutil.py:816, in move(src, dst, copy_function)
    815 try:
--> 816     os.rename(src, real_dst)
    817 except OSError:

PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\\Users\\MYNAME\\Dropbox\\PC (2)\\code/31924000106314.txt' -> 'C:\\Users\\MYNAME\\Dropbox\\PC (2)\\clean_texts\\31924000106314.txt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 27
     25 for x in text_sample:
     26   #try:
---> 27     htrc_text_processing.clean_vol(x, out_dir)

File c:\Users\MYNAME\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\htrc_text_processing\__init__.py:204, in clean_vol(vol_dir_path_list, out_dir)
    201         for n, page in enumerate(pages):
...
    836         copy_function(src, real_dst)
--> 837         os.unlink(src)
    838 return real_dst

PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\\Users\\MYNAME\\Dropbox\\PC (2)\\code/31924000106314.txt'
```

Please let me know if you have any advice for how to bypass an error in a loop! Thank you :)

Comment: In the error message you have shown, the `try` statement is commented out.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thanks for noting! I commented it out in this example so that Python would show the error message -- when I run the `try` and `except: pass`, the error message itself doesn't show, but the same error occurs (the loop stops). I'm wondering if there's a way to bypass the error so the loop will keep running, despite the error!

Comment: How do you know that the loop stops?

Comment: @mkrieger1 The GitHub library clean_vol() command includes a progress bar that indicates how many texts the command has processed. It reads 0/n and stops at 0 when the error message is outputted, unfortunately.